# Creating svg clip-path polygon for Firefox that mimics css clip-path polygon used on Chrome

Tags: css, svg, clip-path

I have a hero image (full width / 70% height div with background image) that I am applying a mask to make the lower edge into a bit of a down arrow.  I set it up using css clip-path with percentages so it scales nicely across different viewport sizes.

```
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 96%, 50% 100%, 0% 96%);
clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 96%, 50% 100%, 0% 96%);
```

It performs as expected in compatible browsers like Chrome, but of course fails in Firefox.  I am trying to create a svg to use with the url() function which Firefox is supposed to honor.  But have struck out.

I understand that svg's can not use percentages, so have tried using 0.0=0%, 1.0=100% and 0.XX for everything in between but that doesn't seem to work or perhaps the svg is not scaling to cover the hero image div.

```
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip-shape" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <polygon points="0 0, 1.0 0, 1.0 0.96, 0.5 1.0, 0 0.96" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Is there a way to convert these percentage based css polygons to an svg that will work in Firefox?  And any tricks to getting it to scale across different viewports? (preferably without having to add JS, definitely without jQuery)

While Firefox's shortcomings don't effect the page in a bad way, it would be nice to present the same scroll down encouragement on all browsers.

Comment: The SVG conversion seems fine to me. Can we see a demo?

Comment: it works http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/LZVNrM but  how did you link the svg to your html ? you don't tell :)

Comment: https://www.pedalerspubandgrille.com/test/tours-test.htm is my test page.  the svg is inside the html down at the bottom of the page.  I have it in the css as `clip-path: url("#clip-shape");`

Comment: and your declaration is a relative path from an external css pointing to `ppgv2016-test.css#clip-shape` which obviously doesn't exists. Change it to `url(yourHTMLFILE.html#yourSVGElement)`

Comment: @Kaiido - yes that did the trick, so how does one define the css in a separate style sheet for use on all pages?  Can the svg be included in the style sheet or does it need to be in the html?

Comment: It can be included in the css file, thanks to [data URIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs). It can also be an external svg file, and it can also be in your html file if your path is correct. Depending on the size of your svg markup and what you need to do with it, you can choose whatever fits the best (for a one time icon, I'd use a dataURI version, As soon as I may need it in different pages, I use a file, and when I need to be able to edit it through js, I use the html choice (it's quite rare though))

Comment: @Kaiido - Thanks for the help